# reCAPTCHA sitekey not sent on AJAX code for verification

Tags: ajax, recaptcha, sweetalert

So, I've been working on a project that citizens can report problems on public places for the municipal government by filling a little form after selecting the place on Google Maps.
We need to implement reCAPTCHA for validation and stop/slow people from spamming our servers.

The data inputted in the form is sent through AJAX to an API that redirects it to add-problem.php but when I add `'g-recaptcha-response'` and `recaptcha.getResponse();` on my formData, the code stops working.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("description", description);

formData.append("pic", picture[0]);
formData.append("cpf", cpf);
formData.append("status", 1);
formData.append("keyword", keyword);
formData.append("type", "add-problem");
formData.append("place_id", $("#name").attr('data-id'));
formData.append("g-recaptcha-response", recaptcha.getResponse());


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../../back/api/api.php',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#loader").show();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#loader").hide();
        console.log("success");
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data.error) {
            swal('Error', data.msg, 'error');

        } else {
            swal({
                title: 'Sucess',
                text: data.msg,
                type: 'success',
                onClose: () => {
                    location.reload();
                }
```

The error on my console log is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (municipe.php:467)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

I also tried to send the code statically creating a var and attributing the secret key into it, but I had the exact same error. What could it be?

**EDIT:** So... I realized what was the problem. Basically, I was sending a var called "g-recaptcha-response" throught the AJAX but my PHP was trying to receive one named as "recaptcha-response". That fixed the problem with my SweetAlert Modal!